# p:confirmDialog how to change the image and text color

Tags: css, image, primefaces, modal-dialog, graphic

I need to display a confirmation dialog using prime faces. But I need to have a custom icon( yellow triangle ) along with red text. By using the following I am getting a blue triangle with black text and I am not sure how to use my icon as well as style the dialog text.

```
    <p:column id="billing_address_unassign"
    headerText="#{billingAccount_msgs['addresses.table.column.unassign']}"
    styleClass="col10">
    <p:commandButton immediate="true" id="address_unassign"
        styleClass="cart-button-class" icon="delete"
        title="#{billingAccount_msgs['unassign.address.tooltip.text']}"
        oncomplete="unassignBillingAddressConfirmationDialog.show()">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{billingAddress}"
            target="#{billingAddressBean.selectedBillingAddress}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

  <p:confirmDialog appendToBody="true"
id="unassignBillingAddressConfirmationDialog"
styleClass="confirm-dialog"
message="#{billingAccount_msgs['unassignBillingAddress.confirmation']}"
header="#   
    {billingAccount_msgs['unassignBillingAddress.confirmation.dialog.header']}"
   severity="alert" widgetVar="unassignBillingAddressConfirmationDialog">
```

Comment: Can you post your css as well?

Comment: .confirm-dialog {
 margin-top: -300px;
 margin-left: -300px; 
}

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own yellow icon and then place your icon instead of the default one in the confirm dialog. The text can be changed to red by simply using css.

Add the following to your css file:

```
/*Red text in confirm dialog*/
.ui-confirm-dialog .ui-dialog-content p { color: red; }

/*Yellow triangle in confirm dialog */
.ui-confirm-dialog .ui-dialog-content p span { background-image: url("#resource['images:yellow-triangle.png']}") no-repeat}
```

Comment: Actually I tried the CSS change you suggested, but only the text color changed to red but still seeing the default image.By the way , open curly bracket was missing from the css which you had mentioned..ui-confirm-dialog .ui-dialog-content p {
 color: red; 
}

.ui-confirm-dialog .ui-dialog-content p span { 
 background-image: url("#{resource['images:warning32.png']}") no-repeat;
}